# ViewPager2 with RecyclerView not displaying correctly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I've been working on an app that uses a vertical RecyclerView inside a fragment, all inside a ViewPager2 object with a tabLayout. I can't seem to figure out how to make all these things work together. Currently, it looks like I got it to show the recycler view with the data but the tabs aren't showing up and the items in the list are spaced like they're different pages. Could someone explain how I'm messing up?

It looks like this:

[image: Current app look]

I'd like it to be like this:

[image: What I'd like it to look like]

Here's the code so far:

## Classes

### MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Mapbox Access token
        Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.mapbox_api_key));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(mapboxMap -> mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.DARK, style -> {

            // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments


        }));

        ViewPager2 pager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        ViewPageAdapter pageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        pager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout2);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, pager,
                (tab, position) -> {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            tab.setText(getString(R.string.stats_tab));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tab.setText(getString(R.string.news_tab));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            tab.setText(getString(R.string.symptoms_tab));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            tab.setText(getString(R.string.safety_tab));
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }).attach();

        // Get data
        new StatsLoader("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", pageAdapter, pager).execute();

    }
}
```

### StatsFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class StatsFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    JSONArray covidData;

    public StatsFragment(JSONArray data) {
        covidData = data;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_page, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter.ListViewHolder> mAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(covidData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

### StatsLoader.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class StatsLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

    Exception exception;
    String urlString = "";
    static JSONArray covidData = new JSONArray();
    ViewPageAdapter pageAdapter;

    public StatsLoader(String url, ViewPageAdapter adapter) {
        super();
        urlString = url;
        pageAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public JSONArray doInBackground(String ... urls) {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
            covidData = json.getJSONArray("Countries");
            ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < covidData.length(); i++) {
                list.add(covidData.get(i));
            }
            SortJsonArray sortJsonArray = new SortJsonArray();
            sortJsonArray.sortArray(list, "TotalConfirmed", false);
            covidData = new JSONArray();
            for (Object object : list) {
                covidData.put(object);
            }
            return covidData;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray coviddata) {

        if (this.exception == null) {
            Log.d("Check", "Works!");
            pageAdapter.addFragment(new StatsFragment(coviddata), "Stats");
        }

    }


}
```

## Layouts

### activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@null"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350sp"
                android:apiKey="@string/mapbox_api_key"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:title="" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/view_page" >

        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### view_page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_view">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### list_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="14sp"
        android:layout_margin="15sp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="40sp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/name"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/name"
                android:contentDescription="Image of country flag" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cases"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing list_view LinearLayout height to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***for tablayout*** :

take/make tablayout outside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

***and for "list are spaced"*** :

make `wrap_content` height in view_page code

also  list_view LinearLayout height to wrap_content

***hope it helped :)***

Comment: It seems like it helped but now it's just not showing any data . Do you know why that might be? The code is the same, with the changes you suggested. It's just there are no items. Also, I'm accepting your answer since it did fix the issue I asked about :)

Answer (score 0):

In your  list_view , Use your parent layout height wrap_content not match_parent

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="14sp"
    android:layout_margin="15sp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="40sp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/name"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/name"
            android:contentDescription="Image of country flag" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cases"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```